# JMeter fails with "Network is unreachable: connect" when run via command line

Tags: networking, jmeter, load-testing

I have a simple test, 1 request to login and a subsequent request after that which works fine if I run the test via the JMeter UI (v4.0) However when I run the same test via the command line it fails with the error message:

```
Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException/Non HTTP response message: Network is unreachable: connect
```

This was working just a day ago and I'm not entirely sure what changed or why it works in the UI but not the command line. I'm using the UI to debug and need the command line to simulate hundreds of requests but it fails even with a single request. Any pointers as to what I could look at?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a properties file plug-in for JMeter to read in my properties file and for some reason when running my test plan via the command line the properties file was not been read at all. Adding the "-q" flag to my command to explicitly (albeit redundant if you ask me) specify the properties file resolved my issue. Not sure if this is an issue with JMeter (v4.0) or perhaps Java (10.0.4) which at the time I believe isn't officially supported by JMeter. Hopefully this helps anyone else that may run into this issue in the future.